# How to set default options fro selectize, When options load from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I try to create a Select input, for my forms and I used Selectize.js,

This is good, but I have a little problem with that.

I loaded my options, from server to add the data, and its okay.

When I try to create my data editor, I must load the last data in form inputs.

In Select box, I loaded the options, and I want to set some of them as selected by default .

I Wrote this code:

```
var $select = $(this).selectize({
create: false,
valueField: 'id',
labelField: 'title',
searchField: ['title'],
plugins: ['remove_button'],
preload: true,
render: {
    item: function (item, escape) {
    return '<div>' +
         (item.title ? '<span class="title">' + escape(item.title) + '</span>' : '') +
         '</div>';
    },
    options: function (item, escape) {
        return '<div>' +
            (item.id ? '<span class="title">' + escape(item.id) + '</span>' : '') +
            '</div>';
    },
},
onDelete: function (values) {
    return confirm(values.length > 1 ? 'آیا شما میخواهید  ' + values.length + ' مورد را حذف کنید؟' : 'آیا شما از حذف این مورد اطمینان دارید؟');
},
load:function(query, callback){
    $.getJSON( url,{mdl:mdl,action:action,id:id}, function( res ) {
            callback((res.select))
    });
}
```

});

And I tried this code to set default :

```
var selectize = $select[0].selectize;
selectize.setValue("1");
```

It's not working ...
I tried this code :

```
var selectize = $select[0].selectize;
var opt = {id:1,title:"عمومی"}
selectize.addOption(opt);
selectize.setValue("1");
```

It works , but, in this solution, I must add selected option TWICE firstly from the server and secondly in JavaScript.

Please Help Me.
Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution :

Changing the code like this solved everything :

```
var $select = $(this).selectize({
            create: false,
            valueField: 'value',
            labelField: 'title',
            searchField: ['title'],
            maxItems: 3,
            plugins: ['remove_button'],
            preload: true,
            render: {
                item: function (item, escape) {
                    return '<div>' +
                    (item.title ? '<span class="title">' + escape(item.title) + '</span>' : '') +
                    '</div>';
                },
                options: function (item, escape) {
                    return '<div>' +
                    (item.id ? '<span class="title">' + escape(item.id) + '</span>' : '') +
                    '</div>';
                },
            },
            onDelete: function (values) {
                return confirm(values.length > 1 ? 'آیا شما میخواهید  ' + values.length + ' مورد را حذف کنید؟' : 'آیا شما از حذف این مورد اطمینان دارید؟');
            },
        });
        var selectize = $select[0].selectize;
        $.getJSON( url,{mdl:mdl,action:action,id:id}, function( res ) {
            selectize.addOption(res.select);
            selectize.addItem(res.select); 
            var value = [1,2,3,4];
            selectize.setValue(value);

        });
```